# Know the last used documents in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file

Is there a way to list the last used files using cocoa (or objective-c) functions?

I would like to have something like "recent documents"

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `-[NSDocumentController recentDocumentURLs]`. It returns an array of URLs representing the locations of the documents recently opened by your application.

---

**Edit based on comment:** In that case, you need to use the Launch Services API. For example:

```
- (NSArray *)globalRecentDocumentsURLs {
    LSSharedFileListRef recentDocsFileList;
    NSArray *recentDocsFiles;
    NSMutableArray *recentDocsURLs = nil;
    UInt32 seed;

    recentDocsFileList = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL,
        kLSSharedFileListRecentDocumentItems, NULL);
    if (! recentDocsFileList) return nil;

    recentDocsFiles = (NSArray *)LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(recentDocsFileList,
        &seed);

    if (recentDocsFiles) {
        recentDocsURLs = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (id file in recentDocsFiles) {
            CFURLRef fileURL = NULL;
            LSSharedFileListItemResolve((LSSharedFileListItemRef)file, 0,
                &fileURL, NULL);
            if (fileURL) [recentDocsURLs addObject:[(id)fileURL autorelease]];
        }

        [recentDocsFiles release];
    }

    CFRelease(recentDocsFileList);

    return recentDocsURLs;
}
```

Comment: Sounds good but I would like to have it for all applications and not only mine. Thanks.

Comment: @AP I’ve edited the answer with a method that returns an array with the global recent documents for the user.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was lokking for.